# What is the difference between connection pooling and max_connections?

Tags: database, postgresql, sequelize.js, amazon-rds

I am using Postgres with [Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/v3/) as the ORM / query interface. Recently we started hitting some errors:

```
SequelizeConnectionError: remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections
```

Looking into it, the problem seems to be related to the connection limits set for Postgres, but I was having some trouble figuring out how to relate the client-side pooling settings with the Postgres settings:

On my postgres 9.4 database (on Amazon RDS), my `max_connections` is defaulted to 26:

```
SELECT name, setting FROM pg_settings WHERE name='max_connections';
+-----------------+---------+
| name            | setting |
+-----------------+---------+
| max_connections | 26      |
+-----------------+---------+
```

In Sequelize, I have my pool set to:

```
pool: {
  max: 10,
  min: 0,
  idle: 10000
},
```

Some questions:

- In general how does the pool relate to `max_connections`?
- Does each connection in the pool take 1 count out of the `max_connections`?
- Does this mean that the pool max must always be smaller than the `max_connections`?
- Would lowering the idle timeout on the pool help free connections faster?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This below query will help you in finding out why you have so many connections

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity
```

**In general how does the pool relate to max_connections?**

Max value in your pool states the number of connections you have set in your pool. In postgresql, `max_connections` are the number of connections you have set in your database server. So each connection from your pool takes 1 value out from `max_connections`

Setting `max_connections` to 26 is pretty low, I suggest you to increase the set value.

**Does each connection in the pool take 1 count out of the max_connections?**

Yes, each connection takes out 1 count.

**Does this mean that the pool max must always be smaller than the max_connections?**

Yes, pool max must always be smaller than the max_connections

**Would lowering the idle timeout on the pool help free connections faster?**

Yeah, this definitely helps but not the perfect solution in this case.

Possible reasons!!

1. Sometimes, there might be a connection leak, then database might get 10 times as many connections than usual.
2. Also a common problem is something like that client side app crashing and leaving connections open and then opening new ones when it restarts

And also, did you check the `superuser_reserved_connections` variable value, please see this [post](http://serebrov.github.io/html/2015-09-22-aws-postgresql-max-connections.html), this might help you!!

Are you using Heroku for connection pooling?

[A bit more detailed explanation here](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Number_Of_Database_Connections)

Comment: Thanks! This was very helpful. We are not using heroku, our apps are deployed on EC2.